IntelliCode setup (beginner)
so basically i'm trying to setup up intellicode with vs code. I got it to work one time but then i was not able to acess my files and running the file was not an option either. What am i doing wrong?
And do you have some tips for starting with vs code (Settings,Extensions,...)
Thank you!
Changed my language to pylance, and changed the .json file (not visible anymore). tbh idk what i did most of the time now it looks normal but some extensions are not working.
